# Froala Text editor _ref.editor.setAtEnd is not a function

Tags: reactjs, text-editor, froala

Using FroalaEditor and fetching instance by ref. while insert and pointing cursor position getting issues like **_ref.editor.setAtEnd is not a function**

```
<FroalaEditor
  ref={(ref: any) => (_ref = ref)}              
/>

const insertText = ()=> {
_ref.editor.html.insert(e.value);
    _ref.editor.events.focus();
    _ref.editor.setAtEnd(); <--Getting issue here
}
```

Issue:
[image]

Expected: Want to work without any red error.

Answer (score 0):

`setAtEnd` works on a `selection` - https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/methods/#selection.setAtEnd

this would solve the error highlighted.

`_ref.editor.selection.setAtEnd(_ref.editor.$el.get(0));`

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with the passed in parameter though.

Which version of Froala are you using?

Comment: I am using "react-froala-wysiwyg": "^3.2.7". The parameter is optional not required